# Docker compose not mounting volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Just setup docker toolbox in Windows 10 and I am having a little issue with my docker containers. When I do docker-compose up, the instance will start but nothing is mounted in my /var/www/html directory. If I open Kitematic I see the container and when I click on volumes I do not see the local folder set. Here is what my docker-compose.yml looks like.

```
web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - app/:/var/www/html/
```

Do I need to specify the absolute path to my local directory? The app directory is in the same folder as the docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @VonC answer, it's different when using `docker-compose` since the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) mention

> You can mount a relative path on the host, which will expand relative
>   to the directory of the Compose configuration file being used.
>   Relative paths should always begin with `.` or `..`

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to specify the absolute path to my local directory?

Yes. [The doc mentions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

> The `host-dir` can either be an absolute path or a name value.
>
> - If you supply an absolute path for the `host-dir`, Docker bind-mounts to the path you specify.
> - If you supply a name, Docker creates a named volume by that name.

In your case, `app/` would be considered as a name, not as a host folder.